# How to get only some lines from source code file in Github?

Tags: github, github-api

How to get the code snippet pointed by a URL that directs to specific lines of a source code (as shown below)?

**URL**: https://github.com/buckket/twtxt/blob/6c8ad8ef3cbcf0dd335a12285d8b6bbdf93ce851/twtxt/cache.py#L44-L51

**Code snippet:**

```py
    def from_file(cls, file, *args, **kwargs):
        """Try loading given cache file."""
        try:
            cache = shelve.open(file)
            return cls(file, cache, *args, **kwargs)
        except OSError as e:
            logger.debug("Loading {0} failed".format(file))
            raise e
```

Comment: I realized this is tagged `github-api`, so it seems I misunderstood the question. I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get only selected lines from a file using the GitHub API.

The part after the `#` in the URL is called a *fragment*, and it is not sent over the wire to the remote server.  Instead, it is interpreted by the user-agent (e.g., the web browser) to select a particular location or portion of the resource (the web page).  This part is done entirely client side, and when done through the GitHub web interface, is implemented in JavaScript.  Therefore, the server never knows you've requested only a portion of the file.

The GitHub API doesn't provide only selected lines because in general this is more expensive and harder to implement than providing only the whole file.  For example, someone may, against best practices, have checked in a file with CRLF line endings, which would need to be parsed and handled specially.  In addition, there is no meaningful way to represent lines or any sort of partial data in a PDF or JPEG file.  All of these cases would require special parsing and evaluation in addition to reading the entire file out of the repository.  It is far, far more efficient to simply hand you the entire file and let you decide how you'd like to parse it or interpret it in your program.